# Typescript shadowed variable

Tags: typescript

I'm using TSLint in a TypeScript project and it's complaining about the variable `i` in the following code:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < body.children.length; i++)
    {
        body.children[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
```

The message is `'Shadowed variable: 'i' (no-shadowed-variable)'`

Is there anything wrong with this loop and what would be the correct way of doing a for loop in TS?

Comment: Could you add all code of this method? Do you have another i in you code? One of the solutions you can try to rename i and all should work fine.

Answer (score 23):

Shadowing means declaring an identifier that has already been declared in an outer scope. Since this is a linter error, it's not incorrect per se, but it might lead to confusion, as well as make the outer `i` unavailable inside the loop (where it is being shadowed by the loop variable.)

You can rename either of the `i` variables, but if you add the rule `"prefer-for-of": true` to your `tslint.json`, TSLint will suggest an elegant solution in this case:

```
for (const child of body.children) {
    child.classList.remove('active');
}
```

(provided `child` hasn't been declared already :-)